# What is the difference between ZLayer.scoped and ZLayer.fromZio?

Tags: scala, zio

I am confused by many different ways in ZIO to do what seems to be the same thing (at least to my noobie eye).

In particular, something like this:

```
val layer: RLayer[ServiceA with ServiceB, ServiceC] = ZLayer.scoped {
  for {
     a <- ZIO.service[ServiceA]
     b <- ZIO.service[ServiceB]
  } yield new ServiceCImpl(a, b)
}
```

vs

```
val layer2: RLayer[ServiceA with ServiceB, ServiceC] = ZLayer.fromZIO {
  for {
     a <- ZIO.service[ServiceA]
     b <- ZIO.service[ServiceB]
  } yield new ServiceCImpl(a, b)
}
```

Are these two snippets doing the same thing? If not, what is the difference? If yes, why are there two of them? When would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

In your case, they are doing the same thing. And there's actually a 3rd way with `ZLayer.fromFunction`:

```scala
ZLayer.fromFunction(ServiceCImpl _)
// or:
ZLayer.fromFunction((a: ServiceA, b: ServiceB) => new ServiceCImpl(a,b))
```

Which is IMHO the simplest.

---

What is the difference then?

- `ZLayer.scoped` is to be used when the service you're creating needs some scoped resources (like opening a file and closing it automatically when "stopping" the service, or a database connection)
- `ZLayer.fromZIO` is to be used when there's no resource to manage but still there are potential errors and creating the service is represented as a `ZIO`
- `ZLayer.fromFunction` is to be used when none of the above apply, that is when creating the service just needs some other dependencies but it cannot fail and doesn't need to manage any resource

See also [ZLayer reference documentation](https://zio.dev/reference/contextual/zlayer/).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I know about `fromFunction`, and my understanding is it's a "shortcut" for a simple case of `fromZIO`. But about scoped resources, can you please elaborate how it works? What exactly is the "sope"? If I do `ZLayer.scoped(ZIO.from(Source.fromFile("foo")))` will it close the file automatically at some point? When exactly? And how does it know how to "close" my resource?

Comment: TBH I'm still struggling a bit with the "scope" and the "magic" behind it. I _think_ what you wrote wouldn't manage it automatically, you'd need to use `acquireRelease` stuff. But I can't say more with certainty.